# How to make a singleton in PHP4?

Tags: singleton, php4

How do I make a singleton in PHP4? Is static available in PHP4?

Comment: Just as a note, PHP4 is deprecated and you should make serious efforts to upgrade your servers and code base to PHP5.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, singletons are possible.  [Here's how](http://abing.gotdns.com/posts/2006/php4-tricks-the-singleton-pattern-part-i/).